# Paginating the combined results ofa union

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm still a little new to graphql and Apollo. But I'm curious, if I create a search query that returns a union of two types, how would I go about modifying the combined results of that union. Using the Apollo Docs example ([Unions and interface](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/unions-interfaces/)):

```
union Result = Book | Author

  type Book {
    title: String
  }

  type Author {
    name: String
  }

  type Query {
    search: [Result]
  }
```

```
const resolvers = {
  Result: {
    __resolveType(obj, context, info){
      if(obj.name){
        return 'Author';
      }

      if(obj.title){
        return 'Book';
      }

      return null;
    },
  },
  Query: {
    search: () => { ... }
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`)
});
```

After both the Book and Author resolvers complete, let's say I have 200 results, 50 books and 150 Authors. If I wanted to limit that to 100 of either, sorted alphabetically, how would I access the resolved array before return it to the client? The Apollo Server type definitions has a IResolverOptions interface with a resolve function, but if I add that to my Result resolver I get an error saying that Result.resolve is defined in the resolver but not the schema.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking. The array of results would be accessible inside the `search` field resolver where you return it.

Comment: That hadn't even dawned on me and now I feel like an idiot. Thank you @DanielRearden.